# Power Query Error "We expected a renameoperations value"

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

When I try to close and apply my queries I get an error "We expected a renameoperations value." I also get this error when I try to load more on the column drop downs. Does anyone know what this error means? Below is the function that produces the error.

```
(tbl) =>
let
    OldColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(tbl),
    NewColumnNames = {"Class", "SubClass", "Style Number", "Attribute 1", "Attribute 2", "Attribute 3", "Attribute 4", "Color", "Size", "SKU", "Units Sold", "Comments", "On Hand", "In Transit", "On Order"},
    CombineColumnNames = List.Zip({OldColumnNames, NewColumnNames}),
    ChangeColumnNames = Table.RenameColumns(tbl, CombineColumnNames)
in
    ChangeColumnNames
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code. See [ask]

Comment: Does the table you are passing in have the same number of columns as you've defined in the NewColumnNames list? Would have to test it, but that sounds like an error that might come up if it wasn't the case?

Comment: Yes thank you. I found I had some edge cases that were producing different column counts.